# How to make hibernate entity display only require fields

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have entity with 4 fields

public class User{

```
@Column(name="email")
private String email;
@Column(name="pass")
private String pass;
@Column(name="user_name")
private String userName;
@Column(name="user_last_name")
private String userLastName;

...setters and getters

}
```

and methods that return this entities in JSON format.

```
{"email":"sdhjfg@com",
 "pass":"1234",
 "userName":"asddsa",
 "userLastName":"weq"
}
```

But sometimes I need to display only fist 2 fields

```
{"email":"sdhjfg@com",
 "pass":"1234"}
```

Comment: Interesting story. I have a dog, and I often take the train. But... do you have a concrete question?

Comment: edited, hope it is more specific

Comment: Use a DTO, or a [JsonView](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring).